# phram.ko insertion does not create a /dev/ entry or /proc/mtd entry

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

My kernel command line is restricting memory to 159Mi.

```
insmod phram.ko phram=phram-test,0x9f00000,1Mi

phram: phram-test device: 0x100000 at 0x9f00000
```

no device gets created in /dev/mtdchar/phram-test
/dev/mtdchar does not exist.

I do have an mtdparts listing in my kernel command line, but I figured when phram inserts, it will append itself to the list.

mtdchar and mtdblock are built as part of the kernel (=Y)

Does anyone have suggested next steps for debugging this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the vendor kernel had commented out a line in mtdcore.c that is particularly needful:

```
//err = add_mtd_device(mtd);
```

FML